# How to get field name from input file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I need to get source field name for input type file in Codeigniter. I have multiple input file with names generated based on id like `"upload_file_12, upload_file_13, upload_file_(n)"`

I know input file is using `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`, and that's why they not available in

```
$this->input->post(); # (which have input field name as array key)
```

But if i use `$_FILES` then I need to hard-code the name, or at least the prefix

```
$_FILES['upload_file_'.$i]
```

which i don't mind using, but is there any way to get the field name like using `$this->input->post()`?

Edit:

For example :

```
<input type='file' name='upload_file_12'>
```

I need to get the `name='upload_file_12'` part, which not in part of `$_POST`, but `$_FILES`.

Comment: I don't believe ci had that. Only for get and post. And tbh the only thing it does is access the post array and check if it's set. The way you are doing it is fine. That being said ci does have an uploader class where you just specify the name of the field, but again that's not much more different than what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `foreach` for `$_FILES`

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key; # It's the key that you need
}
```

Comment: *sigh*, i'm so dumb i forget that `$_FILES` is an array. While it seems that CI did not provide any function similar to `post()`, this fulfill my requirement. Thanks @Yahya

Comment: I hoped that in Codeigniter I had something to deal with this. But soluction best is use the global $_FILES variable.